# Why doesn't the grep command work when I apply it to Apache Kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka, grep

I am new to Apache Kafka and I need to find some information in Apache Kafka by a specific word, so using cmd I make the following request:

```
/opt/kafka/bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --topic ...--zookeeper... --grep "Some specific word"
```

I don't have a filename, I need to do a search in output.
When I apply this request, I just see the output without any filter. What's wrong?

Comment: Can you point us to any documentation that says `--grep` is a valid flag?

Comment: Unfo no, I just have been advised to use the flag --grep  this way

Comment: Advised by who? You can run `kafka-console-consumer` on its own to see all supported flags

Answer (score 2):

I believe that `--grep` is not a correct switch for this command, I would advise you this approach (use a pipe character and obviously you can still use the `--zookeeper` switch):

```
/.../kafka-console-consumer.sh --topic ... | grep "Some word"
```

Comment: `--zookeeper` should be replaced with `--bootstrap-server`, though

Comment: The interesting thing is that when I use  a pipe character  | grep "Some word" there is no reply from the system. No reaction. But when I used --grep the system started working and gave a lot of results, unfortunately without the filter I needed

Comment: @IrinaBurtovaya Make sure you are adding `--from-beginning`. Otherwise, you only see events that are actively being produced, not existing records